# Can you set a line-height for sIFR3 r-436?

Tags: sifr, css

I have tried setting a line-height for sIFR3 in both the sifr-config.js and my web stylesheet but neither seem to apply a line-height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `leading` parameter which corresponds to the flash value, not the "line-height" CSS property, e.g.:

```
sIFR.replace(fontName, {
        css: [
            ".sIFR-root { background-color:#000000; color:#ffff33; font-size:24px; leading:-10; }",
            ".bottom { color:#FFFFFF; font-size:15px; }",
        ],
        selector: "#featured-articles .widget-info p",
        fitExactly : false,
        transparent: true,
        tuneHeight: 0,
        tuneWidth: 0
    });
```

Comment: Just a note regarding your example code, the `background-color` is the fallback in case transparency isn't supported, so it shouldn't be`transparent` itself.